# MVC partial views (or editor templates): append index to input name for multiple use of form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, mvc-editor-templates

How can I add an index,  to input names and ids in forms that are used multiple times in one view?

I have created a form for photo rotator that provides the ability to edit a context-specific caption for each photo (billboard). I need to be able to include multiple instances of the form fields for this so the admins can edit all of the captions for a rotator's set of photos in one view, and so I need a way to keep  ids and field names unique.

Editor templates automatically add a prefix, but when I loop over the photos like this:

```
<% foreach (var billboard in Model.Billboards ) {  %>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(x => billboard, "BillboardForm")%>
<% } %>
```

It simply adds "billboard_" as the prefix, which doesn't solve my problem.

I'd like to append the <strike>rotator id</strike> billboard id to the end of each input name and id:

```
<form action="/Rotators/Edit/5" method="post">                  
    <input id="billboard_21_RotatorId" name="billboard_21_RotatorId" type="hidden" value="5" /> 
    <input id="billboard_21_ImageId" name="billboard_21_ImageId" type="hidden" value="19" />
    <label for="billboard_21_Title">Title</label>
    <textarea cols="20" id="billboard_21_Title" name="billboard_21_Title" rows="2">Title</textarea>
    <label for="billboard_21_Caption">Caption</label>
    <textarea cols="20" id="billboard_21_Caption" name="billboard_21_Caption" rows="2">This is the caption</textarea>
    <select id="billboard_21_TopicId" name="billboard_21_TopicId">
        <option value="1">1st option</option>                   
    </select>
</form>
```

Any easy way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz download this [sampel code](http://blog.codeville.net/blogfiles/2010/January/ListEditorDemo.zip) from [steve sanderson's](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) blog post. it does not directly relate to your question. But in demo project you will find BeginCollectionItem html helper that is changing the prefix scope for input or series of inputs. This can give u a starting point
**Edit:**
in ur editor template u can use following method from steve's code like

```
using(Html.BeginHtmlFieldPrefixScope("BillBoard" + Model.ID.ToString())){
<label>Image<label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Image)
<label>Caption</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Caption)
}
```

if ID is property of your model and has value e.g 4 then u will have html like

```
<label>Image</label>
<input name = "BillBoard4.Image" .../>
<label>Caption</label>
<input name = "BillBoard4.Caption" .../>
```

Comment: furthermore if u can edit ur question to include intended html and code of your editor template it will help us answer the question more precisely.

Comment: @Muhammad: OK, I've added some example markup of my desired result.

Comment: @Muhammad: Sanderson's technique adds a random guid to the names, which makes them entirely un-predictable. I'd like to, instead, add a known, unique "rotator" id

Comment: @Faust what i understand from ur markup is that billboard is your prefix but what about 21 is it value from db or something. Moreover, generating names this way will hamper the model binding and your inputs will not map to the your model/viewmodel. you can consider generating names with . instead e.g billboard.21.name. for that you have to write custom htmlHelper

Comment: @Muhammad: "billboard" is in there for clarity only, so it's clear what kind of id 21 is. Sure I can go with billboard.21.name for model-binding purposes. So what might a custom htmlHelper that achieves this look like??

Comment: @Muhammad: thanks -- is that Razor syntax?  I like the looks of it.

Comment: @Faust glad it helped. yes it is razor syntax

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The features used below may not have existed 4 years ago...
>   Firstly, you don't have to use beestings any more, the @ syntax used
>   in the Razor examples is far cleaner.

The method you're calling is in `System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions`:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
)
...
```

Your approach:

```
@foreach (var billboard in Model.Billboards ) {
   @Html.EditorFor(x => billboard, "BillboardForm")
}
```

The body of expression `x => billboard` is a `ConstantExpression`.

This approach results in the appropriate scope applying in the EditorTemplate:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.BillBoards.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.BillBoards[i], "BillboardForm")
}
```

If `Model.BillBoards` is an array, the expression `x => Model.BillBoards[i]` can be described as

```
SimpleBinaryExpression{NodeType:ArrayIndex}(
    Left: ConstantExpression,
    Right: ConstantExpression
)
```

If `Model.BillBoards` is an `IList<T>`, the expression `x => Model.BillBoards[i]` can be described as

```
InstanceMethodCallExpressionN(
    Method:RuntimeMethodInfo(IList<T>.get_Item (Int32 index)),
    Object:PropertyExpression(ConstantExpression),
    Arguments:[ConstantExpression]
)
```

The overloads of `EditorFor()` that accept Expressions check the expression body's Type and NodeType and construct the scope accordingly.

This code should be equivalent if you don't have anything else inside the loop:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.BillBoards, "BillboardForm")
```

If you only have a read-only view and an editing view, you can rename your templates and remove the second parameter. Assuming `BillBoard` is your Model class, rename `BillboardForm.cshtml` to `EditorTemplates/BillBoard.cshtml`, then change the code to

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.BillBoards)
```